# Web Application in Tomcat, how to connect to MongoDb

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat

I was wondering which is the correct way to access a MongoDb Server from a web application inside Tomcat.
 The MongoDb documentation describes perfectly how to connect with MongoClient, but is it possible to define a datasource and manage a connection pool?
As far as I see, it is not. So I guess the entire managing of the connection pool has to be done manually, as the parametrical configuration of the server ip and port?

Comment: My approach would be to create a service that uses mongo Java drivers to connect to Mongodb  and then expose the service endpoints to the web application as an api.